# How to create association (in pivot table) for one to many relationship Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, associations

I am trying to create a link between two models, `Post` and `PostVersion`. I think the issue may be arising from naming conventions, but I am not sure. The relationships between these models are defined as follows:

`Post`

```
public function postVersion()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostVersion::class);
}
```

`PostVersion`

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

I have created a table called `PostPostVersion` which is structured like this:

```
Schema::create('post_post_version', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->integer('post_version_id');
        $table->primary(['post_id', 'post_version_id']);
    });
```

After I have created a `$post` and a `$postVersion`, I try this:

```
$post->postVersion()->associate($postVersion);
```

But it does not work, and I do not receive an error. How would I fix this and create the link between the `Post` and `PostVersion`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not like that. You should create 2 table: `posts` & `post_versions`

In `posts` table:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    //
});
```

In `post_versions` table:

```
Schema::create('post_versions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
    $table->string('version');
    //
});
```

Then after creating a post:

```
$post->postVersion()->save(new App\Comment(['version' => 'v1.0.0']));
```

Comment: I also have both of those tables, but they are used for different information relevant to the original post and subsequent post versions. Why can I not use an intermediary table in this situation?

Comment: @hoolakoola In one to many relationships you don't need a pivot table. Pivot table is useful only in many to many relation.

Comment: The `PostVersion` has data like `comments` and `date`, so I can see comments by date and after a certain date and so on.